# Hundredth Derivative From Taylor's polynomial for $\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Find the hundredth derivative (at $x=0$) from Taylor's polynomial for $\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^4}$.

I keep getting the wrong answer; can someone help?

---

I have tried to solve this by extracting the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the sum
$$x^2\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-x^4)^i.$$
I see that the coefficient is $1$ and since, by Taylor's formula, this should be $1=\frac{f^{(100)}(0)}{100!}$ I get that the hundredth derivative is $100!$, but this doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: Please explain if you want to compute $f^{(100)}(x)$ or just $f^{(100)}(0)$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i should find $f^{(100)}(0)$.I have tried to count it from geometric series $x^{2}*\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(-x^{4})^{i}$. My conclusion is that from here we can see that the factor for $x^{100}$ is 1, and this should be equal to what we get from taylors formula $ \frac{f^{(100)}(0)}{100!}$.  And here we set $\frac{f^{(100)}(0)}{100!}=1$ so $f^{(100)}(0)=100!$

Comment: How can the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in that series be nonzero? Which value of $i$ would that correspond to?

Comment: @user305180 It's better to include such work in your post; I edited it in for now. I may have made an error though; I'm not sure whether you intended to say that $100!$ was the mentioned wrong answer that you got, but it seemed like you wouldn't be asking if it wasn't? Feel free to fix whatever bad thing I've done ;) (And it's still not clear to me if you wanted $f^{(100)}(0)$ or $f^{(100)}(x)$ - so you might want to clarify if I've gotten that wrong)

Comment: @MiloBrandt You have edited it right, i wanted $f^{(100)}(0)$ and my wrong answer was 100!.Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $x^4+1=\Phi_8(x)$, i.e. the roots of $x^4+1$ are the primitive eighth roots of unity $\frac{\pm 1\pm i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

The residue theorem or equivalent techniques give:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(x)&=&\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}\\ 
&=& \frac{1-i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{1+i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}}-\frac{1+i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x-\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}}-\frac{1-i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x-\frac{-1-i}{\sqrt{2}}} \end{eqnarray*}$$

hence $f^{(100)}(x)$ equals:
$$-100!\cdot\left[\frac{1-i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{101}}+\frac{1+i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{101}}-\frac{1+i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{101}}-\frac{1-i}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{-1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{101}}\right].$$

Since $f(x)$ is an analytic function and the radius of convergence of its Taylor series at $x=0$ is one,
$$ f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} = x^2-x^6+x^{10}-x^{14}+\ldots = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^{n} x^{4n+2} $$
for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$. That also gives:
$$ f^{(100)}(x) = 100!\cdot\sum_{n\geq 25}(-1)^n\binom{4n+2}{100}  x^{4n+2-100} $$
for any $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $1/(1+x^4)$ as an alternating geometric series in $x^4,$ then multiply all terms by $x^2.$ I believe that this would lead to the answer $0.$

Comment: I believe that by *the hundredth derivative* the OP means $f^{(100)}(x)$,not just $f^{(100)}(\color{red}{0})$.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify on @Justpassingby's response: for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$ we can write
$$ \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} = x^2\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-x^4)} = x^2 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{4n} = \sum_{n  = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{4n+2}$$
Since in this expansion the coefficient of the $x^{100}$ term is zero ($100$ is not in the form $4k + 2$) we conclude the hundredth derivative is zero.